# How to get object value with dynamic key in $project in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

I want to retrieve a value from an object with a dynamic key

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "sweatshirt",
    "price": {
      "INR": 45.99
    },
     "currency": 'INR'
  }
]


db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "pricenew": "$price.currency"
    }
  }
])
```

If I do `price.INR` it will work fine but here I have currency dynamic, so I want something like `price.currency` but here currency is coming like "INR" and it gives no data.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: `obj.price[obj.currency]`

Comment: Duplicate [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @ChrisG I am trying to do it in $project aggregation and not in just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `price` object to an array using `$objectToArray`, filter it and then convert it back, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: {
                      "$objectToArray": "$price"
                    },
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.k",
                        "$currency"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                in: {
                  k: "pricenew",
                  v: "$$this.v"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            _id: "$_id"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pt-HIOJ_sSF)